# How to remove header for webview

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to remove the header for my webview but I can't find any methods within the webview class so I'm assuming that I need to use the webengine object and possibly execute some javascript or something to remove the header. I'm not sure at all how to go about doing that though. If anyone knows, I'd also like to know if there's a way to customize the layout of other elements on the webview (scroll bars on the side). Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class testwv extends Application
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Application.launch(args);

  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
  {
    WebView wv = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = wv.getEngine();
    engine.load("https://www.google.com");

    Button btn = new Button("YT");
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.getChildren().addAll(wv);


    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Web Viewer");

    stage.show();
  }

}
```

[image: header]

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `stage.setTitle("Web Viewer");` and hence you see it. If you want it to be blank try this. Let me know if you were looking for something else.

```
stage.setTitle("");
```

Comment: I actually just want to remove the whole thing altogether. I don't just want it to be blank yenno